# route view problem

Tags: route

Trying to check IP status to show a customer

root@server [~]# telnet route-views.routeviews.org
Trying 128.223.51.103...

Nothing happens, but telnet is enabled

Any idea why it may hang for minutes?

Using CSf firewall, Centos 4.4 box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine here. If you're not up yet, I'd guess telnet is blocked somewhere along the way.